# dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

Tags: package-management

Every time I want to install something with terminal it shows this warning message but it continue to install, what's the problem?

> dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with another package after some funny things with apt. The solution is relative simple.

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic
```